Popup div doesn't stay on screen
I've created a form with a div on it that looks like this:
<div id="imageModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close" onclick="CloseImageModal()">;
     <img id="Image2" src="test" alt="View Document" runat ="server"/>
  </span>
</div>

In the code behind I get an image from the database and set the img.src to the image, my code:
FileName.Value = SaveToFile(MyConnection, ParticipantID, DocumentID) ' Save the image to a file, return filename

Dim sInternalFile As String = "C:/appimages/" & FileName.Value
Dim sMineType As String = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(sInternalFile)
Dim ImageBytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(sInternalFile)
Image2.Src = $"data:{sMineType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(CType(ImageBytes, Byte()))}"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ShowImage", "ShowImageModal();", True)

The jquery function ShowImageModal:
<script>
    function ShowImageModal() {
        $("#myimagepop").show();
        var modal = document.getElementById('imageModal');
        $("#imageModal").show();
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

I get the image, set the img.src and then call the jquery function with the script manager.  There's a flash and then nothing.  So I opened the debugger and placed a break on the first line of code in the jquery function, when I hit the breakpoint, the image is displayed on the screen but disappears when the function completes its run.  I tried adding return false; and Event.PreventDefault(), but neither worked.  Why doesn't the div stay visible on the screen?

are you using Bootstrap  ?

No, I'm using jquery.

how is the code behind set to fire?

The jquery function is executed when this line of code,. Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ShowImage", "ShowImageModal();", True) is executed in the code behind.  I think what's happening here is a page refresh.  How would I prevent that?

At what moment or event do you want the image modal to be triggered?

I execute the code on a button click in a gridview via rowcommand.

I am going to suggest you adopt either a Bootstrap modal dialog, or a jQuery.UI dialog.
The bootstrap one looks rather nice, but is VERY jinky in terms of how you set them up, and how you display such dialogs.
The jQuery.UI is super reliable, works well, but unfortunately the default styling of such dialogs looks like something from 1990. However, despite the beyond looking ugly part, I still suggest adopting a robust dialog library such as jQuery.UI dialogs in place of attempting to roll your own.
Next up:
 $("#myimagepop").show();

What is above supposed to do? In your posted markup, there is no such control with a control id of myimagepop. So, whatever this is supposed to do, it clearly can't work, and your posted markup clearly has no control with an id="myimagepop".
So, let's go with the jQuery.UI dialog. Only downside (compared to the assuming we have bootstrap is that you have to setup + install jQuery.UI (include jQuery.UI in your page).
And when testing such code, of course create a blank test page, get the dialog working, and THEN and ONLY then introduce such working code into the page with the GridView.
So, assuming jQuery, and also jQuery.UI is installed, then a proof of concept code for a button to work would be this test code:
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show popup"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="Button1_Click"
            />

        <div id="mycoolpopup" style="display:none">

            <h4>This is my cool dialog pop</h4>
            <div style="text-align:center">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"
                    Width="128px"
                    Height="128px"
                 />
            </div>
        </div>


        <script>

            function showmypop(sbtn) {
                var btn = $(sbtn)
                myDialog = $("#mycoolpopup")
                myDialog.dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: "My Cool pop title",
                    modal: true,
                    sizable: true,
                    width: '430',
                    closeText: "",
                    position: { my: 'left top', at: 'right bottom', of: btn },
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: {
                            text: "Ok",
                            click: function () {
                                myDialog.dialog('close');
                            },
                            class: "btn btn-info"
                        }
                    }
                })
                myDialog.dialog("open")
            }


        </script>

And our code behind for the button is this:
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim sFile As String =
        "c:\test\balls\b2.png"

    Dim sMineType As String = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(sFile)

    Dim ImageBytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(sFile)

    Image1.ImageUrl =
        $"data:{sMineType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(ImageBytes)}"

    Dim sJava As String =
        $"showmypop('#{Button1.ClientID}');"

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,
                                        Page.GetType,
                                        "myjava", sJava, True)

End Sub

And I do assume a script manager has been dropped into this page.
And the result of above is now this:

As noted, I don't like the 1990's default style, but we can fix that with this style sheet:
    <style>
        .dialogWithDropShadow {
            -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        .dialogWithDropShadow .ui-dialog-titlebar {
                background: white;
                border: none;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .dialogWithDropShadow .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
            display: none;
        }

    </style>

And then to the .dialog code, add this:
   $(".ui-dialog").addClass("dialogWithDropShadow")
   myDialog.dialog("open")

And now we have this:

And note how we are able to position the pop dialog to the lower right of the button click. With a GridView, then of course if the button is on the right side of the GridView, then we would position like this:
position: { my: 'right top', at: 'left bottom', of: btn },

So, build a test page, add jQuery.UI to the page, and then test above code.
Once you have this all working, then adopt the above design to your page with the GridView.

I had already looked at the jquery dialog and I need more granular control of the data and cannot get the document large enough for the user to view properly, and I don't always know if the document in question is a image file or some other type such as pdf.  I've posted an solution to my question.

don't see any solution posted just yet. All of those reason STRONGLY suggest that using a jQuery.UI dialog will work even boatloads better then rolling your own. You have to VAST increase your explain as to why a jQuery.UI dialog would not work MUCH better given your follow up reasons? Regardless, your posted code not even close to being working or workable anyway. All the jQuery.UI dialog does is "display" a div, and what content you place inside of that div is 100% up to you anyway. I mean, is not your posted goal to display some div content?

Just posed my solution.

I appreciate your response, It did help me come to a solution.

Ah, very well then, so changing the goal of display of content in the existing page, and then changing to that of opening a whole new page? Sure, that's looks to be a different road and goal, but one that is certainly viable. Not sure at all why this changed the issue of saving some file to a database first, or not, and displaying content in a div is displaying content in a div, or as you gone, opening a whole new page. I often say display a pdf, and even use a dialog to do so - for that I use a "object", or even a iFrame. However, once again, a jQuery.UI dialog with a iFrame also works well

Well, the way I approached the problem simply won't work for the level of control I need over the document.  So I switched to opening a new tab with an aspx page that displays the document full screen and gives me total control over the page and how the document is handled.  I do this with the following code:
Dim sMineType As String = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(MyDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(index)("filename"))
Dim ImageBytes As Byte() = MyDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(index)("Document")
Session("ImageSource") = $"data:{sMineType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(CType(ImageBytes, Byte()))}"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('Document.aspx','_blank');", True)

Thus far this method of displaying the document checks all the boxes in respects to the requirements.  I also don't have to write the file in the table to disk and then read it again.  Drops several server round trips.
